# Write a Shell Script to read the data from data.csv file and print the records into a new file having salary greater than 5000

Tags: shell, awk, sed, grep

data.csv   is the input file

```
eid,ename,esal
101,Raju,8000
106,Sanjay,5000
109,Anjali,4000

awk '$esal > 5000 { print $esal }' data.csv
```

the above is the command which i have tried.
the output is:

```
eid,ename,esal
567,pinky,4000
```

Expected output is:

```
eid,ename,esal
101,Raju,8000
```

Comment: Change FROM `awk '$esal > 5000 { print $esal }' data.csv`  **TO** `awk -F',' '$3 > 5000 { print $3 }' data.csv`

Comment: **OR** if you want to search first field number from your headers(1st line), which can be any field and you DO NOT want to hardcode. Then try following code: `awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=","} FNR==1{for(1;i<=NF;i++){if(i=="esal"){field=i;next}} $field>5000 {print $field}' Input_file`

Comment: nothing printed for this

Comment: Try my 1st(updated) and 2nd code also now and let me know how it goes.

Comment: If Ravinders suggestion doesn't work for you then you probably have DOS line endings, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45772525/why-does-my-tool-output-overwrite-itself-and-how-do-i-fix-it.

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this if you want to address columns by name:

```
awk  'BEGIN{FS=OFS=","}
    FNR==1{ 
    for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) {
        header[$i]=i
        printf("%s%s", $i, i==NF ? ORS : OFS)
        }
    next
    }
    $header["esal"]>5000
' file
```

Prints:

```
eid,ename,esal
101,Raju,8000
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$ awk -F, 'NR==1 || $NF>5000' file
```